# Node not joining baseline topology

Tags: ignite

I need nodes to join the baseline topology automatically so that they get an equal share of the data. This has to happen programmatically without resorting to the *control.sh* script.

When the 2nd node starts, the first one reports

```
[11:17:55] Joining node doesn't have stored group keys [node=eb8e1b5e-9c1a-4272-84ea-08a1a89a4fb8]
[11:17:55] Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=9747b94a, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=12, offheap=6.2GB, heap=4.0GB]
[11:17:55]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
```

and the new node

```
[11:17:55] Ignite node started OK (id=eb8e1b5e)
[11:17:55] Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=eb8e1b5e, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=12, offheap=6.2GB, heap=4.0GB]
[11:17:55]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
```

I read that the auto-adjust was needed so I start the nodes this way

```
// Starting the node
ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustEnabled(true);
ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustTimeout(30000);

ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE);
```

What is the meaning of "Joining node doesn't have stored group keys"?

See code [here](https://github.com/crawler-commons/url-frontier/blob/ignite/service/src/main/java/crawlercommons/urlfrontier/service/ignite/IgniteService.java#L125)

Answer (score 0):

The message is related to [TDE](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/security/tde), it means that there are no cache groups with configured encryption on the joining node.

Actually, it shouldn't be printed in the case when Encryption is turned off, I've created a JIRA ticket for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16854

Comment: not sure why TDE is enabled, IIUC the authentication is not disabled by default and my code does not call cfg.setAuthenticationEnabled(true)

Comment: cfg.setAuthenticationEnabled(true) is not related to TDE. Do you have configured EncryptionSpi in the IgniteConfiguration?

Comment: No, I don't. See https://github.com/crawler-commons/url-frontier/blob/ignite/service/src/main/java/crawlercommons/urlfrontier/service/ignite/IgniteService.java

Comment: @JulienNioche, sorry for the confusion, indeed, Ignite, unlike GridGain, checks the encryption keys for cache groups on each node join, even when Encryption is actually turned off. I've created a JIRA ticket for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16854