# Apache Ignite node startup error - Joining node doesn't have stored group keys

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I made some changes in my dev Ignite cluster to enable persistence. Now when I start my cluster (2 node, version 2.9.0), first one starts just fine but second one doesn't seem to be. As the first one shows in log the below error

```
[14:18:59] Joining node doesn't have stored group keys [node=4f20534b-1e44-46af-b81a-34d35807abd8]
```

I saw a similar question, whose answer mentions of TDE or transparent data encryption. But I have not enabled encryption to data anywhere in my config.

What could be the problem? Please help.

Comment: Run JPS and see whether there are any nodes that you don't know about which do have encryption turned on.

Comment: And share your persistence configs if you changed only that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16854) that Ignite checks a list of known encryption keys for cache groups even in case TDE is turned off.

Actually, it doesn't affect the node start, just an info message is printed.

You can find the discussion regarding that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843364/11196452).